# location fields are not appearing on feed mapping while location module is used inside field collection

Tags: feeds, entities, location

I want to import field collection through feeds but since I’m using location module inside the collection module due to this it’s not appearing on target list as you can see the below screen short.
**Field collection**
[image]

**Feeds Mapping**
[image]

Guy can you please help me and I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in `location_feeds.module` under function(`location_feeds_feeds_processor_targets_alter`) under first 'if statement' there is only mention that when node is selected in feeds on that case show all location fields so for solving this issue we just need to add when node or `field_collection_item` is selected on that case location fields should be appear...
steps:
Go to

> path= modules/location_feeds/location_feeds.module

add `$entity_type == 'field_collection_item'` || to first statement of "if condition"
like this:

```
function location_feeds_feeds_processor_targets_alter(&$targets, $entity_type, $bundle_name) {

if ($entity_type == 'field_collection_item' || $entity_type == 'node') {
```

// location.module logic

```
$settings = variable_get('location_settings_node_'. $bundle_name, array());
```

// Only add fields when collecting locations

```
if (isset($settings['multiple']['max']) && $settings['multiple']['max'] > 0) {
_location_feeds_location($targets, $settings);
}
```

Save and clear all caches(`admin/config/development/performance`) and then check it...

Comment: But Location module developers should add this new condition on their new patch and i'm specially waiting for this new patch...